# "Report Data Pane" Missing in Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 Integrated Shell

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I'm missing the "Report Data Pane" feature in Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 Integrated Shell.  Shouldn't it be at the bottom of the "View" menu selection?  I've tried CTRL+ALT+D with no success.

I want to use the Report Data Pane feature to create Microsoft Dynamics NAV 2013 reports.

Answer (score 0):

Could be that something has overridden the hotkey or menu hasn't loaded. Click on the report body, then CTRL-Q to put focus on the Quick Launch, then type in "Report Data"  (without quotes).

Now can someone tell me how to get VS to remember to show this pane for reporting projects.